# How to control collection name of Mongodb on python, like put element of list to name of colletion using 'for'

Tags: python, mongodb, collections, rename

I'm setting up database with different collection in MongoDB, and only way to set the name of collection is  '  collection = db.code  '

I want to make group of collection with list ex) list = ['1','2','3','4']

collection1 name is '1'
collection2 name is '2'
... such like that

in console there is an way    .renameCollection()   but not applied in pycharm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now I finally find a way. for someone who will have same problem like me, I will write the answer

not using  test_collection = db.test_collection 
using test_collection = db.[name of collection] with "for"

```
import pymongo as mongo
connection = mongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = connection.testdb

a = ['test1', 'test2']

for i in a:
    test_collection = db[i]
    test_collection.insert_one({'username': 'John'})
```